# Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 Team Edition and migrating repository from Visual Intercept Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

We have a tool called Visual Intercept Manager that was used to track all the issues and incidents. We use it to store all the application changes, enhancements and change requests. For those who is familiar with Visual Intercept Manager, feel free to jump in and read forward.

So, my question is to get to understand the process it requires to move the the repository from Visual Intercept Manager to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. Have you had any success with it and what are the materials online to get start on it. Perhaps, if you have time, can you describe how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you will need to export your VI items to excel and import them into TFS.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/81a3237e-5118-4d60-9a91-c266e135afce/